# Actualizar una tabla con condición basada en una lista de valores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quisiera saber si se puede actualizar (update) un campo "A" de una tabla "A"  según (where) los valores de campo "id" indicados de la siguiente manera (1, 2, 3, 4, 5.....,x)

ejemplo de lo que quisiera poder hacer:

```
Update TalblaA
Set Value1= 1
Where ValueID = (1, 2, 3, ..... ,100)
```

estoy utilizando MS-SQL server 2008 y 2012.
gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usa [`IN`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Determina si un valor especificado coincide con algún valor de una subconsulta o una lista.

```
Update TalblaA
Set Value1= 1
WHERE ValueID in (1, 2, 3, ..... ,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

De la siguiente manera vas a actualizar el CampoA a '1' a todos esos ID's

Update tablaA
Set CampoA = 1
where CampoID IN (1,2,3,4,..., 100)

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

logre hacerlo con **IN** de la siguiente manera.

```
Update TalblaA
Set Value1= 1
Where ValueID IN (1, 2, 3, ..... ,100)
```

espero que le sirva a alguien mas.

Comment: Ya hay una respuesta para tu pregunta que satisface lo que pedías, sería mejor que marques esa como respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por dejarnos saber qué es lo que te funcionó. Pero en este caso, la forma correcta de hacerlo es aceptando la respuesta que te funcionó, no posteandola tú también

Comment: inmediatamente luego de postearla vitu respuesta que no se habia actualizado en mi navegador.